# Spring Boot validating request parameters

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

I am trying to learn Spring Boot and working on a simple REST API which I develop a simple calculator.

I have a service class annotated with `@Service` and it has a simple method

```
public double calculate(String operation, double num1, double num2) {
        ...
}
```

And I am calling this method from the controller like

```
@GetMapping("/calculate")
public double calculate(@RequestParam(value = "op") String op,
                        @RequestParam(value = "num1") double num1,
                        @RequestParam(value = "num2") double num2) {

    return calculatorService.calculate(op, num1, num2);
}
```

I want to validate these parameters(Whether num1 and num2 are numeric and all parameters should be not null). What is the best practice to validate the request parameters for Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what validation you want to perform.

One way would be to use validation annotations on the parameters themselves.

For example, `@NotNull`, `@Min`, `@Max`, etc. These particular ones can be found in `javax.validation:validation-api`, but there are many others (and you can build your own).

```
@GetMapping("/calculate")
public double calculate(@RequestParam(value = "op") @NotNull String op,
                        @RequestParam(value = "num1") double num1,
                        @RequestParam(value = "num2") double num2) {
```

The `@NotNull` validation will ensure that `op` is not null - you might want to use a `@NotEmpty` or `@NotBlank` annotation to ensure that the actual value of `op` has a length > 0 or a trimmed length > 0 respectively.

As Cristian Colorado points out in their comment below, Spring will automatically fail validation (or endpoint matching) if either `num1` or `num2` are not valid double values.

Comment: Using BigDecimal makes sense but I do not need to check the value range of my parameters. I just need to check whether they are numeric or not.

Comment: If num1 is not numeric, spring will not be able to bind the parameter and either would throw a ServletRequestBindingException or just will not find a proper endpoint to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

As you have told that you want to validate only `Number` **@NumberFormat** Annotation is there. The @NumberFormat annotation applies to subclasses of java.lang.Number (Integer, Float, Double, BigDecimal, etc.)

```
@NumberFormat(style=Style.NUMBER)
```